# Execute local shell script to remote server in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a deployment script checked in the Github which I checkout with the source code in the pipeline. I need to execute this shell script to the remote server to perform the tasks (create backup, start / stop Jboss). I am using ssh agent to ssh into the remote server. How can I execute this within the Jenkins pipeline, and get the output from the commands back to the pipeline?

Thank you